# How can I return 2 values in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitextfield

I'm try to return a **UITextField** and a **UIView** (A rectangle box) at the same time so I can have a text field inside a rectangle UIView coloured box, but I can only return one value at a time. Is it possible to return 2 values? Or can I edit a text field to have a rectangle coloured background? Also, the UITextField is being called programatically, not from the story board.

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: add UITextField and UIView to an array. return array.

Comment: @RemingHsu A dictionary might be better than an array. Look for the keys instead of having to worry about which object is at which index of an array.

Answer (score 3):

you can `return` two values with help of `block`.

Please find `code` below it may be helpful to you.

```
- (void)getUIControlles:(void (^)(UITextField * objTextFiled, UIView * objView))completionBlock {


    UITextField * textFiled = nil;
    /*
     do code here for textfiled
     */

    UIView * viewDemo = nil;

    /*
     do code here for Uiview.
     */

    completionBlock (textFiled, viewDemo);
}

- (void) testMethod {

    // Call function with following way.

    [self getUIControlles:^(UITextField *objTextFiled, UIView *objView) {

//        objTextFiled = This is your textfiled object
//        objView = This is your view object

    }];


}
```

Comment: Please make sure to check if `completionBlock` is set before calling it in `getUIControlles`

Answer (score 1):

The common way to return multiple independent values in C, C++, and Objective-C is through pointers:

```
@interface MyController (UIViewController)

- (void)getView:(UIView **)viewOut textField:(UITextField **)textFieldOut;

@end

@implementation MyController

- (void)getView:(UIView **)view textField:(UITextField **)textField {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    // ... initialize view

    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    [view addSubview:textField];
    // ... initialize textField

    *viewOut = view;
    *textFieldOut = textField;
}

@end
```

Apple uses this pattern, for example in `+[NSStream getStreamsToHostWithName:port:inputStream:outputStream:]` (which is not in the documentation but is in the header files).

Example use:

```
    UIView *view;
    UITextField *textField;
    [myController getView:&view textField:&textField];
    [myController.view addSubview:view];
```

Another approach is to return one object directly and the other through a pointer:

```
- (UITextField *)newTextFieldWithWrapperView:(UIView **)viewOut {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    // ... initialize view

    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    [view addSubview:textField];
    // ... initialize textField

    *viewOut = view;
    return textField;
}
```

Apple uses this pattern, for example in [`-[NSAttributedString initWithFileURL:options:documentAttributes:error:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/initWithFileURL:options:documentAttributes:error:), which returns the string directly, and optionally returns a document attributes dictionary and an error object through pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've never programming in Objective C but if you insist on returning 2 values, create a Pair class an return that.